# How to get the data for each ad in this page?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I am scraping this page to get data of each Ad: http://www.cars2buy.co.uk/business-car-leasing/Abarth/695C/?

Here is my code in scrapy shell:

```
scrapy shell "http://www.cars2buy.co.uk/business-car-leasing/Abarth/695C/"
for content in response.xpath('//*[@class="pitem"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]'):
          print content.xpath('//*[@class="detail"]/p/text()[2]').extract()
```

but it only extract 48 in each iteration!!
the disered output should be:

> 48 months
>
> 48 months
>
> 48 months
>
> 36 months
>
> 48 months
>
> 48 months
>
> 48 months
>
> 48 months
>
> 48 months
>
> 36 months

according to the ads on the page! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy fix. Try adding a `.` to the front of the second xpath:

```
print content.xpath('.//*[@class="detail"]/p/text()[2]').extract()
```

**Explanation:**

An xpath that starts with `/` means 'start searching at the document root' while an xpath that starts with `.` means 'start searching in the current position' ... so it's very much like navigating directories of a filesystem.

So without the `.` your xpath expression extracted all matching elements that were anywhere on the page ... and did so in each iteration.

**Update/Addition**

This also happens when the xpath expression is used on a sub-element ('selector' in scrapy lingo) like `content` in this example.

Scrapy internally keeps the whole html and starts from the document root when the xpath starts with `/`. Explained in detail here: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#working-with-relative-xpaths

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i though that by using content.xpath not response.xpath, it will just search in the content not in all the page.

Comment: yes, that's what I thought, too when I started using scrapy several years ago. And so I fell for the same weird trap. `content.xpath` can still access the whole document's html and so does your xpath expression start searching from the root.

Comment: thank you for sharing this. it's really what i need.